# Spring ApplicationContextInitializer and properties

Tags: spring

I am learning about ApplicationContextInitializer. 
I was reading an example as shown below which is part of a webapp setup

```
public class MyApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext>{
.....
.....
public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext)  {
String homeKey = ((ConfigurableWebApplicationContext)applicationContext).getServletContext().getInitParameter("homekey");
.................
...............
```

The corresponding web.xml

```
...............
...............
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
          org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
      </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xxx.config</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
        <param-value>com.xxxx.MyApplicationContextInitializer</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>homekey</param-name>
        <param-value>yyyyy</param-value>
    </context-param>
.............
...............
```

I want to duplicate this behavior in NON webapp application, more for learning purposes.

I have modified the MyApplicationContextInitializer as follows

```
public class MyApplicationContextInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext>{
................
......................
public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
............
.............
```

My question is how do I get the "homekey" without the web.xml. I am assuming I can use system properties or use a property file and call methods applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty or applicationContext.getResource(). Can I do this without system properties or property file. The web.xml did not use any property file.

Comment: The web.xml itself is where the property ('homekey) was taken from. It's the very same concept as using the property file. Both represent kind of 'externalized' configuration. Your idea of using 'Environment' abstraction is correct.

Comment: The first approach is already a wrong one imho. Use the `Environment` instead. `applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("homekey")`. Depending on the way the application is launched the system properties/environment, jndi and/or the web context are consulted. That way you can use the same initializer in both situations.

Comment: Thank you all for you replies

Answer (score 3):

If you're currently using Spring Boot 2 and you want to use the nice strongly typed configuration objects ...

```
@Data     // lombok for terseness (getters / setters)
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "my-config")
public class MyConfigProps {

    private String homekey;
    ... 

}
```

... against properties in your `application.yaml` file ...

```
my-config: 
    homekey: yyyyy
    ...
```

... and programmatically retrieve the property class inside a `ApplicationContextInitializer` (which comes up early in the spring lifecycle) then you can use the `Binder` object (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) i.e.

```
public class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableWebApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableWebApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        ConfigurableEnvironment environment = applicationContext.getEnvironment();
        MyConfigProps configProps = Binder.get(environment).bind("my-config", MyConfigProps);
        System.out.println(configProps.getHomekey());
    }

}
```